# jQuery UI dialog with asp.net - Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, master-pages, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an aspx page using a master page that is giving me issues when I try using a jQuery UI dialog.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<link href="/Styles/SiteFramePage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="Screen"/>
<link href="Styles/ArrivalTemplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.12.1.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
    .DisabledCheckout
    {
        background-color:Gray;
        color:Black;
        Width:100%;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    body.waiting
    {
        cursor: wait;
    }
    .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/SMS_JClient.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My div for the dialog is as follows:

```
<div id="ChckDgtDialog" title="Enter Check Digit">
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="ChckDgtDialogError"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="ChckDgtDialogPrompt">Please enter the check digit on the container.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><input type="text" id="ChckDgtDialogTextBox" size="50" onkeypress="isChckDgtDialogSubmit(event)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I also have a script at the bottom of the page that sets up the div as a dialog.

```
$("#ChckDgtDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        width: 425,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": checkDigitValidate,
            Cancel: function () {
                var dialogbox = $('#ChckDgtDialog');
                $(dialogbox).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            stopTimer();
        }
    } );
```

There is a longer script tag within Content1 that on `$(window).load()` will get data and build a table with buttons. Within that script block, there is the following statement which should open the dialog box:

```
$(":button").click(function () {

Option = $(this).text();

if (Option == "Check In") {

    $("#ChckDgtDialog").dialog("open");

}
if (Option == "Check Out") {

    $("#ChckDgtDialog").dialog("open");
}});
```

(There is other logic that gives the if statements more of a purpose, trying to only show what is related to the issue)
However, when a button is clicked, we receive the error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'.

What I find weird is that when we set up all of the properties for the dialog in the script at the bottom of the page, there is no problem. I can tell this portion is working because the div isn't seen on the page and if I remove that it is. It seems like some issue with scope but I've tried moving the part where the dialog properties are set up within `$(window).load()` because in theory, shouldn't the jquery ui script be loaded at that point, but then I get the error on that right away before I even get to trying to open the dialog.

Any ideas on why on the button click we don't have dialog available to us? I'm new to jquery and I'm wondering if there is something with master page or asp.net in general that could be messing with something?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you place dialog initialization code inside the page onload function, that will fix the issue.

Comment: I tried that, I get the "Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' " error on the initialization instead. Its like jquery ui isn't loaded at that point for some reason. Tried both $(window).load() and $(document).ready() with same result.

Comment: You may have to place the <script> tags to the top of the page then, I guess.